# Optimize hold drag cell table in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a table. When a user clicks a cell and drags through others. The cells bettween must highlight. But in my real project have 1000 cells, it so slow, have anyway to optimize my code.

The code

```java
export default function Table() {

    const [start, setStart] = useState(null);
    const [end, setEnd] = useState(0);
    const [selecting, setSelecting] = useState(false);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    let toggleModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    let beginSelection = i => {
        setSelecting(true);
        setStart(i);
        setEnd(i);
        updateSelection(i);
    };

    let endSelection = (i = end) => {
        setSelecting(false);
        updateSelection(i);
    };

    let updateSelection = i => {
        if(selecting) {
            setEnd(i);
        }
    };

    let cells = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < 12*4; j++) {
            cells.push(
                <Cell key={j}
                      inputColor={
                          (end <= j && j <= start || (start <= j && j <= end) ? "#adf": "")
                      }
                      onMouseDown={()=>beginSelection(j)}
                      onMouseUp={()=>endSelection(j)}
                      onMouseMove={()=> updateSelection(j)}

                >
                    {j+1}
                </Cell>
            )
        }

    return (
        <TableCalendar>
            {cells}
        </TableCalendar>
    )
}
```

Here is my full code and demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-noether-4krei

Thannks!

Comment: It works pretty fast on the codesandbox you provided. 
Which laptop/desktop are you using ?

Comment: @UtsavPatel It is slow if you change the number from `12*4` to `12*400`

Comment: Don't see much scope for optimization here.
There is only one loop and he is using the api functions given by react.

Comment: Each cell is copied/created on each render cycle no matter what, seems like there is room for improvement there? Well, just tested this by only defining `cells` array once and mapping it, but it is still creating a new `Cell` component. Maybe with some component memoization some performance could be etched out.

Comment: Replaced the `push` to `map`, seems to need more efforts https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cartwright-kj0lz

Comment: Each cell must implement the shouldComponentUpdate method for optimization. Then only the changed cells re-render

Comment: @SamwellTarly `Cell` is a functional component, so no lifecycle functions, but even when wrapping `Cell` with the `memo` HOC I don't see much improvement. Even after converting the event handlers to higher order functions, UI is still much slower when list gets larger. This is where virtualization really helps.

Comment: Even tried throttling the `updateSelection` handler but that didn't do much and caused some state synchronization issues. https://codesandbox.io/embed/delicate-wave-egpyb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FTable.js&theme=dark